# Сокращение количества условий if

Tags: php, html, база-данных

Заношу в базу данных расцветки. '$rascvet[0] $rascvet[1] $rascvet[2]'

В результате так: "Коричневый Черный Зеленый" или "Черный Белый " и т.д

Вывожу из бд строку,сравниваю и на экран выходит картинка расцветки или комбинации расцветок.

Вариантов получится много. Например: вар1-Черный;Вар2-Белый Черный;Вар3 Черный серый и т.д
Правильно ли будет если для каждого варианта будет отдельное условие и своя картинка?
Или есть какой то более рациональный способ?

Cейчас использую If elseif elseif...

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
do
{



 if ($row['rascvet'] == "Коричневый Белый ") 
echo <img>1</img>'; 

elseif ($row['rascvet'] == "Белый ") 
echo <img>2</img>; 

elseif ($row['rascvet'] == "Черный Зеленый ") 
echo <img>3</img>;

/*и так далее*/
}
```

Comment: код в студию. из этого текста мало что можно понять

Comment: нифига не ясно. лучше напиши какой-то пример более человеческим языком и хотя бы псевдокоде

Comment: `$opts = ['белый' => "2.jpg", ...]` и `<img src="<?= $opts[$row['rascvet']]?>"/>`

Comment: @teran, так просто не выйдет, у него там "Черный чай", "Зеленый чай"  и т.д, и т.п.

Comment: вместо if elseif else используйте: switch

Comment: @Visman я уже с названия переменной `$rascvet` в первом предложении понял, что просто не будет :D

Comment: @teran А что не так с названием переменной?:) Код-просто наглядная схема.Тем не менее,я новичок,хотелось бы знать что не так.

Comment: @Rust просто не надо их транслитом писать :)

Answer (score 2):

Рациональнее создать картинки с таким же название, как и в БД и благодяря этому сделать вывод без условий

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo "<img href=" . $row['rascvet'] . ".jpg">"
```